# How to set up automatic build in Emacs

Tags: emacs, automation

I've done this with Texclipse in Eclipse using a script that is called after every edit or refresh. I wonder if this is possible in Emacs?

For Emacs, I manually compile by calling `M-x tex-compile pdflatex`, then refreshing my pdf view with `M-x tex-compile \doc-view "MyDocument.pdf"`. Has anyone set this up, and is there a tutorial on how to implement this feature?

Comment: perhaps not quite automatic - but have a look at `auctex` http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/ and how it can simplify the workflow - I use it with okular as a pdf viewer which automatically refreshes every time I recompile

Comment: That seems unnecessarily complicated.  If you have AUCTeX installed, a simple `C-c RET` will compile your document and another `C-c RET` should open an appropriate viewer.  If the viewer is clever enough, it will automatically reload (this is viewer- and OS-dependent).  If you use 'vanilla' Emacs, see [section 25.10.3](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/emacs.html#TeX-Print) of the Emacs manual.  I'm sure you could impose some kind of hook to run `M-x tex-compile` after (say) each time you save the buffer, if you really wanted to....

Answer (score 1):

Use "auto-save-buffers", put into your .emacs:

```
(require 'auto-save-buffers)
(run-with-idle-timer 1.5 t 'auto-save-buffers)  
(global-set-key [f7] 'auto-save-buffers-toggle)
(auto-save-buffers-toggle)
```

And then use "latexmk" to compile the *.tex file. To make everthing much faster, you can build a thing called a "format" with pdflatex. Roughly:

```
pdflatex -ini -jobname="Brief" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx "Musterbrief.tex""
```

Then insert into your *.tex file as the very first line: `%&Brief`. This has some disadvantages, e.g. if you change the preamble, you'd have to make a new format...

To open a command window under Windows, you can insert into your .emacs file another shortcut:

```
;; http://stackoverflow.com/a/13509208/1171221
(defun start-cmd () (interactive) 
(let ((proc (start-process "cmd" nil "cmd.exe" "/C" "start" "cmd.exe")))
(set-process-query-on-exit-flag proc nil)))
```

So with M-x start-cmd you get a command line inside the folder of your texfile. This makes starting latexmk a lot faster.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is linux-based.

If you have open your pdf with evince (and other pdf viewer I think but I use evince), it will be refreash after a compilation inside emacs.

In order to not use AUCTeX and compile with a shorter command after the first one, you can use `M-x recompile` that you can bind by adding this in your `.el` file:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "key-bindings wanted")    'recompile)
```

Note that binding will work with other compilation too.